Are there sites that specialize in engine checking old chess books?
I bought some old chess books from the 80's, 90's, early 2000's, and some even older ones. Certainly they are not engine proofed or checked.
Are there sites that are dedicated to checking these books to find where they go wrong or if they are right at all?
And if my particular book is not checked can I contribute my findings if such sites exist?

Sometimes people will talk about engines "cooking" an old puzzle, i.e. finding something the author missed.  https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/40777/where-does-the-term-cook-originate


Are there sites that are dedicated to checking these books to find where they go wrong or if they are right at all?

No. For a very simple reason. Engine checking all the games and analysis in old books is a lot of hard work and nobody is going to do it for free. Add to that the fact that few people are capable of doing it properly. Anybody who does do something like that is going to do it on a limited scale and publish a book containing their fresh analysis.
One such example is described in this answer to this related question. This book, "John Nunn's Chess Course", reanalyses games by Lasker in "Why Lasker Matters" by Soltis (Batsford 2005) and "Emanuel Lasker Games 1904-1940" by Soloviov (Chess Stars 1998), so quite modern books which are in the period when powerful engine analysis was possible. Nunn is quite scathing about the analysis done by both Soltis and Soloviov.
Nunn seems to suggest another reason why poor game analysis exists in books in the computer age, namely that authors have a narrative in their minds based on the results of the games and their opinions of the players and they don't let impartial engine analysis get in the way of the story they tell themselves and their readers. This possibly also provides another reason why this kind of reanalysis is so rare. It involves contradicting a previously accepted narrative.
